# vector and its size and elements all in same row

Tags: c++, vector

Let v be a vector containing 5 elements as:

```
8, 9, 100, 77, 90
```

I need to give an output

```
5 8 9 100 77 90
```

how do i do this in c++? I could not come up with a suitable code as how to control printing size.

```
vector <int> v
v.push_back(8);
// all push back
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{8, 9, 100, 77, 90};

    // Print length of v:
    std::cout << v.size();

    // Print elements of v:
    for (auto value : v)
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << value;
    }

    // Print end-line and flush:
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// Let v be a vector containing 5 elements as 8,9,100,77,90
std::vector <int> v{8,9,100,77,90};

// I need to give an output 5 ...
std::cout << v.size(); // print the size

// ... 8 9 100 77 90
for(auto item : v)
    std::cout << ' ' << item; // print the items

std::cout << std::endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/KMZkLr)

Answer (score 0):

A version that doesn't write an extra "" character at the end of the list:

```
vector<int> v = { 8, 9, 100, 77, 90 };

cout << v.size();

for (auto i : v)
{
    cout << " " << i;
}

cout << endl;
```